# How do I prevent white box(es) (face detection) from showing up on my Canon EOS 60D?

Tags: canon, autofocus, live-view, face-detection

I use a Canon EOS 60D to shoot a separate angle facing the audience at my Church. It works pretty well, except I have one huge issue. Whenever I point it to the audience, a bunch of white boxes start showing up singling out everyone's face, or just a particular face and then I get to switch from face to face. The only way I have been able to take it off is by switching to a large white square box, which is even worse. I'm sending out the camera shot via HDMI Mini- HDMI. How do I prevent my EOS 60D from having these white boxes appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the menu system and look at the fourth page from the left. You should see **AF mode**, second option down. Select this and you will see three options, **Live mode**, **:-) Live mode** and **Quick mode**. Chances are your camera is set to **:-) Live mode** which is the face detection mode, select one of the other two modes and your boxes should disappear.

Comment: This just changes the nature of the overlay, for me :'(